# spl_autoload_register no funciona php

Tags: php

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que tengo un problema al usar la  `spl_autoload_register` en php 8, literalmente lo que hago es ejecutar el siguiente codigo:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class)
{
    echo $class;
});

// resto del codigo ...
```

Y no hace nada, lo que hago es ejecutarlo desde consola con el siguiente comando `php file` y no obtengo nada, ni un error. Realmente llamo a `spl_autoload_register` desde un objeto y una forma mas compleja, pero la funcion simplemente no funciona desde ningun lugar. Me gustaria que por favor me digan si es que estoy entendiendo mal algo, o estoy haciendo algun mal uso de la funcion. Desde ya gracias :D.

### Edit

En base a las preguntas y opiniones que me pusieron en los comentarios hago este edit. Primero es que entonces quiero mostrar el codigo completo. Este codigo lo que quiero que haga es cargar todas las clases de un directorio (pero como digo no hace nada):

```
namespace Classes;

class CommandList
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $clases = array();

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // aqui solo puse el "echo" para mostrar que no ver si se ejecutaba la funcion y no lo hace.
        spl_autoload_register(function($class)
        {
            echo $class;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Agrega una nueva clase.
     * 
     * @return void
     */

    public function addClass(string $class): void
    {
        array_push($this->clases, $class);
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve todas las clases.
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function all(): array
    {
        return $this->clases;
    }
}
```

Y ahora me gustaria responder al comentario que hizo [Wilfredo Aleman](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/553416/spl-autoload-register-no-funciona-php?noredirect=1#comment978094_553416):

- Estoy usando `php 8.1.9`
- Y al usar `__autoload` en lugar de `spl_autoload_register` tengo el mismo resultado. Nada.

Ahora para el comentario que me puso [A. Cedano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/553416/spl-autoload-register-no-funciona-php?noredirect=1#comment978155_553416). Lo que hago para llamar a la funcion es esto:

```
require_once __DIR__ . "/CommandList.php";

use Classes\CommandList;

// Me parece que el crear una instancia del objeto, el constructor deberia de llamarse e imprimir en la pantalla las clases. Lo cual no hace
$app = new CommandList();
```

Ya como ultimo me gustaria agregar que el programa lo ejecuto desde consola como `php programa`. Espero me puedan ayudar. Desde ya gracias :D.

Comment: Que version de `php` estas utilizando , ¿Has probado  utilizar `__autoload()` ?

Comment: No queda claro cómo estás probado el código. Para que `spl_autoload_register()` se dispare debes intentar crear una instancia de una clase y que la misma esté definida claro está. ¿Dónde haces eso? No lo veo en el código que nos compartes.

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: spl_autoload_register no hace nada por si solo... en algun lugar debes crear un objeto de clase en donde se instancia a una clase que dispare la peticion... de lo contrario no pasara nada como indicas.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya edité la publicacion con mas datos e intentando responder a sus preguntas, espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: @WilfredoAleman ya edite la publicacion con mas datos.

Comment: @DFG no te funciona por que spl_autoload_register no funciona igual estando dentro de una clase a cuando esta a nivel de root... mira mi actualizacion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spl_autoload_register` no hace nada por si solo... en algun lugar debes crear un objeto de clase en donde se instancia a una clase que dispare la peticion... de lo contrario no pasara nada como indicas:

[Documentacion](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

Ejemplo:

```php
<?php

namespace Foobar;

class Foo {
    static public function test($nombre) {
        print '[['. $nombre .']]';
    }
}

spl_autoload_register(__NAMESPACE__ .'\Foo::test'); // A partir de PHP 5.3.0

new ClaseInexistente;
```

Output:

> [[Foobar\ClaseInexistente]] Fatal error: Class 
> 'Foobar\ClaseInexistente' not found in ...

***Que pasa en el ejemplo:*** Al primer llamado funcionara correctamente, en el segundo dara error por que no existe la clase.

---

***Como lo implemento yo Clase Autoloader en php:***
Cuando el implementamos `spl_autoload_register` desde o dentro de una clase especifica su implementacion cambia y debemos agregarle un par de cosas adicionales para que tenga el scope necesario.

***Nota:*** compatible con php 7.4 o superior.

index.php:

```php
<?php

use Example\Test;

require_once 'Autoloader.php';
Autoloader::getInstance();
```

Autoloader.php

```php
<?php

namespace Example\Test;

use Exception;

class Autoloader
{

    private static ?Autoloader $instance = null;

    function __construct()
    {
        spl_autoload_register([$this, 'autoload']);
    }

    public function autoload($class)
    {

        $parts = explode('\\', $class);
        if ($parts[0] != 'Example' || $parts[1] != 'Test') {
            throw new Exception('All classes must be on "Example\Test" Namespace.
                                        <br> Namespace Used: ' . implode('\\', $parts));
        }
        unset($parts[0], $parts[1]);
        $filename = implode('/', $parts) . '.php';
        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            /** @noinspection PhpIncludeInspection */
            require_once($filename);
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Class File not Found: ' . $filename);
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance(): Autoloader
    {
        if (!self::$instance instanceof self) self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

como veras para que funciones le he dicho a `spl_autoload_register` que reciba un array en donde se incluya a el mismo `[$this, 'autoload']` en la busqueda de el metodo `autoload` propietario.

Comment: Hola, he intentado lo que me dijiste y tengo exactamente el mismo problema, no me sale nada por pantalla, y me parece que la funcion `test` deberia de mostrar algo en la pantalla

Comment: @DFG no te funciona por que spl_autoload_register no funciona igual estando dentro de una clase a cuando esta a nivel de root... mira mi actualizacion...

Comment: Muchas gracias. Con la actualizacion que pusiste ya pude hacer que funcionara :D.

Comment: de nada pa eso estamos